# How to find more information through DescribeFeatureType for Feature Types of a Layer

Tags: geoserver, describe-feature-type

On the GeoServer web interface, there's a list of feature type details. I can also see this same information by using the WFS operation `DescribeFeatureType`.

How do I find more details about these Feature Types? I need to debug why CQL filtering on a Feature Type is working for one layer but is not working on another layer.

Comment: Have a look at the GeoServer logs. You may need to change the logging level into GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what more details do you need? is the layer not working in the GUI or when you request the `DescribeFeatureType`? what does the log say for the one that is not working?

Comment: There are no errors being thrown in the Geoserver logs, the only difference between the layer that's working is the Feature Details name is different.
The styling is getting applied without applying a filter by a code, I need to filter the style to where `CODE IN ([...ids]). So when I try filtering by codes,tThe layer is not being applied in the GUI or in the png image you request from the endpoint, it is getting applied without the CQL filter.